How can I stop Ubuntu from forcing me to log in when the system is accessed remotely via Splashtop
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS and when I try to access the machine remotely via Splashtop Ubuntu forces me to log in.
Is there a way to stop this from occuring?

Isn't Splashtop a paid product with a free trial? Perhaps as part of the free trial period you are limited to what you can do otherwise it could be a huge security risk. I would say that this is outside the remit of Ask Ubuntu and you should seek assistance from Splashtop support.

Oh I'm paying for it already, I CAN sign in no problem. Thru splash top or Ubuntu. What I would like is to bypass Ubuntu forcing me to login to the machine

do you have to log in as a user when sat at the PC?

No, it is set up to auto log in.

then this suggests a Splashtop issue which you should seek advice about from them.
